# Cycle jQuery slider plugin not sliding properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-cycle

I'm using the [Cycle JS 2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) `jQuery` plugin but it doesn't seem to be sliding correctly when clicking the "Prev" or "Next" buttons.

**Update:** I am trying to get it to slide all 4 sections at once, hence that is why 4 sections using `col-sm-3` are contained within each `.item` block.

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/gutterboy/pen/MaZyZx

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main-slider" class="slider">
  <div class="item row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="" class="content-wrap">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://runnersfeed.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/curry.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image" />
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <h4>Some Title</h4>
          <p class="sub-title">
            I'm a sub-title
          </p>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Illud non continuo, ut aeque incontentae. Honesta oratio, Socratica, Platonis
          </div>
          <div class="link">
            <a href="">Some Link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Details Ends -->
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Col Ends -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="" class="content-wrap">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://www.newsmax.com/Newsmax/files/44/44b1645b-3804-408d-9c64-f68c8f45bc74.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image" />
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <h4>Some Title</h4>
          <p class="sub-title">
            I'm a sub-title
          </p>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Illud non continuo, ut aeque incontentae. Honesta oratio, Socratica, Platonis
          </div>
          <div class="link">
            <a href="">Some Link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Details Ends -->
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Col Ends -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="" class="content-wrap">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://www.interbasket.net/news/wp-content/uploads/Lebron-James-Miami-Heat.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image" />
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <h4>Some Title</h4>
          <p class="sub-title">
            I'm a sub-title
          </p>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Illud non continuo, ut aeque incontentae. Honesta oratio, Socratica, Platonis
          </div>
          <div class="link">
            <a href="">Some Link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Details Ends -->
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Col Ends -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="" class="content-wrap">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/ac1394dbdcca6a36cbf486633b129cd813095ac3/r=x404&c=534x401/local/-/media/USATODAY/USATODAY/2012/11/26/usp-nba_-san-antonio-spurs-at-toronto-raptors-4_3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image" />
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <h4>Some Title</h4>
          <p class="sub-title">
            I'm a sub-title
          </p>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Illud non continuo, ut aeque incontentae. Honesta oratio, Socratica, Platonis
          </div>
          <div class="link">
            <a href="">Some Link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Details Ends -->
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Col Ends -->   
  </div>
  <!-- Item Ends -->
  <div class="item row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="" class="content-wrap">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://i.usatoday.net/sports/_photos/2011/07/11/NBA-lockout-allows-players-to-look-overseas-9V7G6NL-x-large.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image" />
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <h4>Some Title</h4>
          <p class="sub-title">
            I'm a sub-title
          </p>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Illud non continuo, ut aeque incontentae. Honesta oratio, Socratica, Platonis
          </div>
          <div class="link">
            <a href="">Some Link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Details Ends -->
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Col Ends -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="" class="content-wrap">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://static6.businessinsider.com/image/5241a14b6bb3f7c368ab8319/nba-players-might-wear-bizarre-nickname-jerseys-in-2013.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image" />
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <h4>Some Title</h4>
          <p class="sub-title">
            I'm a sub-title
          </p>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Illud non continuo, ut aeque incontentae. Honesta oratio, Socratica, Platonis
          </div>
          <div class="link">
            <a href="">Some Link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Details Ends -->
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Col Ends -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="" class="content-wrap">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://bingemagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/BINGEMagazine-DennisRodman.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image" />
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <h4>Some Title</h4>
          <p class="sub-title">
            I'm a sub-title
          </p>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Illud non continuo, ut aeque incontentae. Honesta oratio, Socratica, Platonis
          </div>
          <div class="link">
            <a href="">Some Link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Details Ends -->
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Col Ends -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <a href="" class="content-wrap">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/ac1394dbdcca6a36cbf486633b129cd813095ac3/r=x404&c=534x401/local/-/media/USATODAY/USATODAY/2012/11/26/usp-nba_-san-antonio-spurs-at-toronto-raptors-4_3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image" />
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <h4>Some Title</h4>
          <p class="sub-title">
            I'm a sub-title
          </p>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Illud non continuo, ut aeque incontentae. Honesta oratio, Socratica, Platonis
          </div>
          <div class="link">
            <a href="">Some Link</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Details Ends -->
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Col Ends -->   
  </div>
  <!-- Item Ends -->  
  <div class="control">
    <a href="" class="prev">Prev</a> |
    <a href="" class="next">Next</a>    
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider {
  margin: 20px;
}

.content-wrap {
  display: block;
  //height: 400px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.image {

  height: 175px;
  overflow: hidden;

  img {
    height: 100%;
  }

}

.details {

  padding: 20px 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;

  h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .sub-title {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .text {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

}

.control {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#main-slider').cycle({
      paused: true,
      autoHeight: 'calc',
      slides: '> .item',
      fx: 'scrollHorz',
      next: '.control .next',
      prev: '.control .prev',
      sync: true
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I have a sneaky suspicion it has something to do with using Bootstrap columns on the items inside the slides, but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Might wanna look at the [carousel](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/demo/carousel.php) addon.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to do here. Are you trying to have slides comprised of multiple columns or are they supposed to be individual slides? "doesn't seem to be sliding correctly" doesn't mean anything if "correctly" isn't explained.

Comment: @vanburen My bad, I will update.